# Merging Data from Different Source to Database

Tags: data-synchronization

I've to compare data from 2 different sources.

From a different source, I need to get college_id, student_id, student_name & I want to check if they are up-to-date in my database. The source is always having accurate data.

One college may have multiple records.

Every time I login I need to keep this information up-to-date in my database. How do I proceed?

Delete & insert option is not recommended by our team. So, how do I compare?

Can any one provide some efficient pseudo code? Should I store source information in 2-D array in Java or in list or how?

If the record does not exist in source but exist in database, then I need to delete it from DB.

If the record exists in source & does not exist in db, I need to insert it in db.

Appreciate if some one can provide an insight whether to use list or 2-D array with some pseudo code.

Thanks!

Comment: How's it `java` question? Sounds perfectly `update XXX set student_name = ? where college_id = ? and student_id = ?` to me.

Comment: I need comparison logic from source data to the data which I've in db....Should I store source data in 2D array & then compare it through loop with database or how ???

Comment: @alf - But the canonical source may have removed their record, so you have to account for that too. Makes it a bit more complicated.

Comment: @cdeszaq see the answer. It's still not "java" :)

Comment: @alf - I agree on the _not java_ part :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to

1. Load all the records from the database
2. Load all the records from the trusted source
3. Find all the records in DB which are not in the trusted source any more. Delete those.
4. Find all the records in trusted source which are not in DB. Add those.
5. Find all the changes records. Update those.

Problem is, you do not specify the *primary key* for your records—so #5 may be irrelevant.

For all others, you need a class which encapsulates a record, implements an `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods (properly!), and a couple of collections, with a knowledge of `removeAll()` and `retainAll()` methods.

Hope that helps.

PS. It is indeed possible to do this incrementally, e.g. if you haven't got enough emory to fill the whole dataset. In this case, you will need an ability to read the records *ordered,* with ordering compatible with equivalence relation.

Comment: In this case, college Id will be unique, so can you provide some sample code with pseduo comments?

Comment: If `college_id` is unique (which is strange, as that means you only have one student per college), create a `Map<Integer, Student>` from `college_id` to a student's id-name pair, read an instance of one from both DB and canonical source, and do the following: `Map<Integer, Student> toDelete = new HashMap<Integer, Student>(dataFromDB); toDelete.keySet().removeAll(dataFromCanonicalSource.keySet()); Map<Integer, Student> toAdd = new HashMap<Integer, Student>(dataFromCanonicalSource); toAdd.keySet().removeAll(dataFromDB.keySet());`

Comment: one college may have multiple students. student_id is also always unique. Basically, I need to take student_id from source & compare it in destination. For simplicity, assume that I need to get student_id, name, address from source & keep them up-to-date in database. Can you provide a sample code now?

Comment: Make a key containing both college_id and student_id, provide proper `equals` and `hashCode`, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You outlined most of the steps in your question. Just go through and, whenever you are syncing:

1. Grab the data you have from your database
2. Compare it to the data from the canonical source
3. Based on the comparison of the data, take the appropriate action in your database:

   - Insert a new record if you didn't have one
   - Update your record if the data is updated
   - Update a *timestamp* on your record so that you know *when* you updated
4. Last step, remove all records from your database that were not updated "recently" based on the timestamps

Comment: I was planning for putting source data in 2D array & then sort that array on collegeId. Now, take the data from database, put it in another 2D array & sort that as well based on collegeId. Then, it would be easy to compare the 2 arrays. Is that approach better & efficient in Java?

Comment: @Mike no, it's neither better nor efficient

Comment: @alf, can you provide an example?